# getting the value in one field and assigning the same value in another field also

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, erb

I want the username also to be email but i don't want to get the value twice from user so i have kept it as hidden field and i tried as shown below and it does not take the value

```
  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.hidden_field :username :value => :email%></div>
```

so how can i get the value of email and put the same value in username field also. please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like `params[:user][:username] = params[:user][:email]` in the controller before using them would work... You might rather put something like this in the model:

```
before_validation(:on => :create) do
  self.username = self.email
end
```

or (also in the model):

```
def username
  email
end
```

But you might rather ask yourself why have two references to the exact same thing? It seems like it is over-complicating the matter, why not just lose username altogether?